# A critical error has occurred on the site

Tags: errors

I´m running my own Ubuntu webserver 18.04.6. I get this error but dont know how to solve it, can someone pls help? Can´t create new posts or pages on the website.

Error: A critical error has occurred on the site.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_metadata() in /var/www/website/wp-includes/meta.php:222 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/website/wp-includes/post.php(2335): update_metadata() #1 /var/www/website/wp-admin/includes/post.php(1659): update_post_meta() #2 /var/www/website/wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php(155): wp_set_post_lock() #3 /var/www/website/wp-admin/post.php(187): require('/var/www/websit...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/website/wp-includes/meta.php on line 222

Comment: Did you recently update WordPress? `add_metadata()` is a core function. If its missing, this could mean an update went wrong and some core files are missing. Simply adding the core files again (of the correct version) should fix the problem.

Comment: I dont know what how to do that? I re-updated the wordpress last update but still same issue

Comment: You may have a file permissions error as well.   There could be several different causes.  You need to go through testing of wordpress (plugin/theme conflicts) and then check to make sure your server is setup correctly.

Comment: [Manual update](https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update) instructions from the WP documentation, if you haven't tried that already. When you're finished look in wp-includes/meta.php and check it contains `function add_metadata(`.